# Rappel embryologique

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Quel est le sens de " rappel " dans cette phrase : Rappel embryologique et histologique de l'organe dentaire.

Il n'y a pas de contexte, car ce sont les plans d'études d'une faculté d'odontologie.

Merci !

Comment: *Il n'y a pas de contexte, car ce sont les plans d'études d'une faculté d'odontologie.* Euh, donc il y a un contexte : les plans d'études d'une faculté d'odontologie...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si le contexte est bien celui d'un plan de cours, il s'agit très probablement d'évoquer en introduction des connaissances censées déjà être acquises sur l'organe dentaire, avant d'introduire de nouvelles connaissances. Rappel a donc ici le sens de « remise en mémoire ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

Rappel est à considérer ici au sens premier :

> Fait, action de rappeler; p. méton., instrument de cette action.

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappel

Comment: Le sens "faire revenir à la mémoire" n'est pas le sens premier de *rappel*.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat quel est donc le sens premier de _rappel_ ?

Comment: Le sens premier de *rappel* est, d'après le TLFi, l'« action de faire revenir quelqu'un dans un lieu ».

Comment: Merci beaucoup !